# Match capital letters and small letters by RegExp

Tags: regex, case-insensitive

I wrote some RegExp pattren like this :

```
SomeText
```

But I want the pattren to match with :

```
Sometext
sOMeTeXt
SOMETEXT
SoMEteXt
```

Somethings like that !

In fact I want to use this

```
\s?[^a-zA-Z0-9\_]SomeText[^a-zA-Z0-9\_]
```

what should i do ?

Comment: What language/regular expression implementation do you use?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In many regex implementations, you can specify [modifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) that apply to a given part of your pattern. Case-insensitivity is one of those modifiers:

```
\s?[^a-zA-Z0-9\_](?i)sometext(?-i)[^a-zA-Z0-9\_]
```

The section between `(?i)` and `(?-i)` will be put into case-insensitive mode. According to [this comparison table](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html), this is supported if you're using .net, Java, Perl, PCRE, Ruby or the JGsoft engine.

Of course, since you're specifying both `a-z` and `A-Z` in your character classes, you could simplify and use the case-insensitive modifier on the entire pattern:

```
/\s?[^a-z0-9\_]sometext[^a-z0-9\_]/i
```

Answer (score 11):

In case you cannot use modifiers:

```
[Ss][Oo][Mm][Ee][Tt][Ee][Xx][Tt]
```

Comment: E.g. regex for mixed case 'yes' where Y isn't optional
`^[Yy]+[es]?[eS]?[Es]?[ES]?$`

Answer (score 10):

You could use the ignore case modifier:

```
/sometext/i
```

Answer (score 2):

Javascript: Works both capital and small letter in any order.

```
value.match(new RegExp(searchkey, "i"))
```

Answer (score 0):

In case if you need to create regEx using the variable names and compare globally with case insensitive use the below example

let str = 'Basappa';
var regex = new RegExp(str, "gi");

Comment: The OP doesn't mention a specific language or technology but you're using JS, and the case-insensitive modifier doesn't necessarily exist in all regex implementations